# Remove two columns at once in a matrix with array_splice()

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the correct result for deleted columns and rows in a matrix, but whenever I remove the first column specified in the `$columnsToRemove` array, the array shifts, and I end up deleting the wrong column. in the following example, how would I delete both the 0th and the 2nd column in each submatrix in one go?

```
$matrix = [
    [1,0,0,2], 
    [0,5,0,1], 
    [0,0,3,5]
];

$rowsToDelete = [1];

$columnsToDelete = [0, 2];

function constructSubmatrix($matrix, $rowsToDelete, $columnsToDelete) {
    foreach($rowsToDelete as $row){
        array_splice($matrix, $row, 1);
    }
    foreach($columnsToDelete as $column){
        for($i = 0; $i < count($matrix); $i++){
            array_splice($matrix[$i], $column, 1);
        }
    }
    return $matrix;
}
```

The return value should be: `[[0,2],[0,5]]`

But I keep getting: `[[0,0],[0,3]]`

Comment: how the return value should be [[0,2],[0,5]] ? there is not such position in your matrix

Comment: @CavidKərimov If we delete the row at index `1` and the columns at indexes `0` and `2` according to the `$rowsToDelete` and `$columnsToDelete` variables, you will have the result `[[0,2],[0,5]]`.

Comment: yes, true. I understand it now :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because if you're deleting multiple rows or multiple columns, then deleting the lowest column in that list will mean that the higher column numbers aren't correct any more.

e.g. with `$columnsToDelete = [0, 2];` once you've deleted column `0`, then column `2` has become column `1`, but your'e still trying to delete column `2`

You need to delete in reverse order to avoid this; so use `rsort()` your `$rowsToDelete` and `$columnsToDelete` before doing the deletion.

```
function constructSubmatrix($matrix, $rowsToDelete, $columnsToDelete) {
    rsort($rowsToDelete);
    foreach($rowsToDelete as $row){
        array_splice($matrix, $row, 1);
    }
    rsort($columnsToDelete);
    foreach($columnsToDelete as $column){
        for($i = 0; $i < count($matrix); $i++){
            array_splice($matrix[$i], $column, 1);
        }
    }
    return $matrix;
}
```